# BeautifulSoup: How to extract tag values?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am quite new to programming and can't seem to solve the following data extraction problem.

This is what my data looks like (yellow = what I am trying to extract):

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcGMs.jpg)

Extracting the title, price and time works fine:

```
# Title
advertTitle = firstAdvert.find_all(
"section", {"class": "aditem-main"})[0].find("h2").text.encode("utf-8").strip().replace("\n", "")

# Price
advertPrice = firstAdvert.find_all(
"section", {"class": "aditem-details"})[0].find("strong").text.encode("utf-8").strip().replace("\n", "")

# Time
advertTimeAdded = advertTitle = firstAdvert.find_all(
"section", {"class": "aditem-addon"})[0].text.encode("utf-8").strip().replace("\n", "")
```

**But my main question is**: How would I extract "*79924470*" from this:

```
<article class="aditem" data-adid="79924470">
```

I have tried for example stuff like:

```
item.find_all("article", "data-adid"}
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Please don't post code in images. Some may not be able to open, thus making them not be able to help. -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A series of selects could be used to get the various elements as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print soup.article['data-adid']
image = soup.select('div.imagebox.srpimagebox')[0]
print image['data-href']
print image['data-imgsrc']
print soup.select('section h2 a')[0].text
print ', '.join([v.strip() for v in soup.select('section.aditem-details')[0].text.strip().split('\n')])
print soup.select('section.aditem-addon')[0].get_text(strip=True)
```

Which displays:

```
79924470
/ref/79924470
https://imgserver.com/012004.JPG
I am a title
12.380€, 50111, Cityname, 25km
Today, 16:19
```

Comment: Wow that's super helpful! Thank you so much Martin.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using BeautifulSoup, you can do this to extract the value of an attribute:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(file, "lxml")
print soup.article['data-adid'] # output : 79924470
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
data = []
for element in soup.find_all({'data-adid':'79924470'}):
    data.append(element['data-adid']
```

This should add every value of `data-adid` to the list `data`.

Comment: I should have explained better. The number "79924470" is different everytime. So I have a list that contains "<article class="aditem" data-adid="79924470">" and I am trying to extract just the number.